# OO javascript for slideshow without jquery can't figure out the error

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm trying for an exercise to create a slideshow without jquery. I'm trying to learn the OO in Javascript.

```
'use strict';

var Slideshow = (function () {

function Slideshow(element, options) {
    options = options || {};
    this.slideshow = document.querySelector(element || '.slideshow');
    this.slides = this.slideshow.children;
    this.slideSpeed = options.slideSpeed || 3000;
    this.autoPlay = options.autoPlay || true;
    this.pauseOnHover = options.pauseOnHover || true;
    this.autoPlayTimer = null;
    this.pause = false;
    this.currentSlide = -1;

    if (this.autoPlay) {
        this.play();
    }
}

Slideshow.prototype.slideIterator = function() {
    this.currentSlide = (this.currentSlide + 1) % this.slides.length;
};

Slideshow.prototype.play = function () {
    if (this.autoPlayTimer) {
        clearInterval(this.autoPlayTimer);
    }

    if (this.slides.length > 0 && this.pause !== true) {
        this.autoPlayTimer = setInterval(this.slideIterator.bind(this), this.slideSpeed);
    }
};

Slideshow.prototype.playTimerClear = function () {
    if (this.autoPlayTimer) {
        clearInterval(this.autoPlayTimer)
    }
};

Slideshow.prototype.pause = function () {
    this.playTimerClear();
    this.pause = true;
};

return Slideshow

})();
```

There is an error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined at line 22.

I think it's because this changes, and it is not Slideshow anymore for some reason...

Comment: Please post your code in your question instead of just linking it

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that setInterval changes the scope so `this` will be window. You can fix it by binding.

```
this.autoPlayTimer = setInterval(this.slideIterator, this.slideSpeed);
```

to

```
this.autoPlayTimer = setInterval(this.slideIterator.bind(this), this.slideSpeed);
```

[MDN bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)